How to keep a passed in temporary vector from getting taking by std::ranges
I have this function:
template<std::ranges::viewable_range T>
auto foo(T&& ts) -> size_t
{
    auto moves_ts { std::forward<T>(ts) | std::views::all };
    return ts.size(); // for illustration - I know ts is a vector.
}

and I call it like this:
auto expected_to_be_3 {foo(std::vector<int> {0, 1, 7})};
// !! expected_to_be_3 == 0 here !!

I can step into the moves_ts construction and see ts getting turned into an std::ranges::owning_view which moves the vector and clears what I consider "my" copy of the vector.
In my real code I don't want this behavior (actual code is two calls deep and I have need to use the vector in the upper method after it gets moved out from under me). How do tell std::ranges not to move my vector?
I have seen this behavior on both g++-14 and Microsoft's latest compiler so I suspect the behavior is by design.
Note: If I instead create a std::vector<int> values{0, 1, 7}; and pass values into foo(), it behaves as I expect but I don't want to have to enforce that.

Don't std::forward if you don't want to forward?

auto moves_ts { std::forward<T>(ts) | std::views::all } -> auto moves_ts { ts | std::views::all }

std::as_const, now it cannot be moved

T&& passes by perfect forwarding, which means the function can take (std::forward) the state of the argument if it was passed as a temporary or passed as an rvalue (foo(std::move(values))).  So if you don't want the function to take the argument's state, don't pass by temporary or rvalue.

Got a solution - create a non_owned() method that returns a std::ranges::ref_view if the range is ownable. I couldn't find something like this already in std::ranges...
template<class T>
concept ownable_c = requires(T&& a) { std::ranges::owning_view {static_cast<T&&>(a)}; };

template<std::ranges::viewable_range R>
auto non_owned(R&& r)
{
    if constexpr (ownable_c<decltype(r)>)
    {
        return std::ranges::ref_view(r);
    }
    else
    {
        return r;
    }
}

template<std::ranges::viewable_range T>
auto foo(T&& ts) -> size_t
{
    auto moves_ts { non_owned(std::forward<T>(ts)) | std::views::all };
    return ts.size(); // I know ts was a vector
}

